# find command with daystart and mmin

Tags: linux, time, find, filemtime

How is `find daystart` used with `mmin`?  `daystart` with `mtime` makes perfect sense, But with `mmin` its confusing.

Let me explain what I do not get:

- `find path -daysart -mtime 0` gives files modified today.
- `find path -daystart -mtime 1` gives files modified yesterday.

How to get files modified today with `daystart` and `mmin`?

Also how to find files modified between `23:59` and `12:00` using `daystart` option and `mmin`?

Comment: Vote to close - this belongs to superuser or Unix&Linux, as it's not a programming question, but a usage question about a standard unix command.

Answer (score 1):

> On how to use `mmin`:

If you try to find what files were *modified* (`m` in `mmin`) between 2 and 6 minutes ago:

```
find path -mmin +2 -mmin -6
```

> to use it with `-daystart`

`daystart` option set the plot at the beginning of today. So if you want files modified between the beginning of today and `12:00`, you need to know how long ago `12:00` was. Let's say it is `14:00`, so it was 120 minutes ago:

```
find path -daystart -mmin -120
```

Maybe [this site](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Age-Ranges.html) will be of help for you.